# How to fix User 1-to-many association when getting NoMethodError "Undefined method 'user_id', did you mean? user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement a User model with a 1-to-many association with articles. So I added a User.rb model with

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :username, presence: true,
      uniqueness: { case_sensitive:  false },
      length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A\S+@.+\.\S+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
      length: { maximum: 105 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

Also added belongs_to: user in the Article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :text, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 400}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

I ran this migration

> rails generate migration add_user_id_to_articles

and this is my migration file

```
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Here is the definition of my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_26_124924) do
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "commenter"
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

And lastly my change function in the articles_controller.rb file:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I ran rails db:migrate so that shouldn't be a problem. I saw some people on Stackoverflow say I should just add

> @article.user_id = current_user.id

but already did that and nothing happened.

I keep getting this error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id' for #)
>   Did you mean?  user

and I don't know what else to try. I'm starting with Ruby on Rails so keep that in mind.

Thanks a lot for reading, hopefully somebody knows a fix.

Comment: There is no `user_id` in articles table. Did your last migration pass?

Comment: Try to restart rails server

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had the server open in another terminal that I had forgotten, and the migration did not in fact pass.

Comment: Happy that it helped :) Restart server is generally a first thing to do when you don't understand why something not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your migration actually runs through; then your `schema.rb` should include the `user_id` column too.

Then, try changing the line creating the new article to:

```rb
@article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
```

Alternatively, you can set

```rb
@article.user = current_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Articles controller, you'll need to add `user_id` into your permitted parameters.

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :user_id)
end
```